# Subprocess maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, subprocess

I am trying to current playing track name from Spotify desktop app window title by using subprocess. In generally, my code is working. But when trying to retrieve song name each five second, i get RecursionError. Where is the problem?

Code1

```
def title_of_window(self,window_class):
    """
        Retrieves the title of application by through 'subprocess'.

        Params:
            window_class (string) -- name of the application to be taken the title
                ex. --> spotify
                    --> filezilla
                    --> putty
                    --> atom

        For this app:
            - window_class parameter must be equal to "spotify"
            - Retrieves the current playing song name from Spotify.

    """
    # Finds id of all GUI apps who running.
    # Ex. -> ['0x200000a', '0x3800007', '0x4800001', '0x2e00010', '0x3600001\n']
    active_windows = subprocess.Popen(["xprop",
                                       "-root",
                                       "_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING"],
                                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    active_windows_ids = active_windows[0].decode("utf-8").split("# ")[1].split(", ")
    #
    # Sends all ids to 'xprop -id' and checks. If app name equal to window_class parameter, return title of this app.
    # Ex. -> get_window.py — ~/Desktop/projects — Atom
    for active_id in active_windows_ids:
        window = subprocess.Popen(["xprop",
                                    "-id",
                                    active_id.strip(),
                                    "WM_CLASS",
                                    "_NET_WM_NAME"],
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
        window = window[0].decode("utf-8").split('"')
        if window_class == window[3].lower():
            return window[5]
```

Mainloop

```
def run(self):
    song = self.title_of_window(self.SPOTIFY)
    if self.temp_song_name != song:
        lyric = self.get_lyric(song)
        self.add_lyric_to_tk(song,lyric)
    else:
        self.add_lyric_to_tk(song, "Not Found")
    self.top.after(5000,self.run)
    self.top.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
File "spotifyLyric.py", line 137, in run
    song = self.title_of_window(self.SPOTIFY)
File "spotifyLyric.py", line 51, in title_of_window
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `self.top.mainloop()` multiple times. You should be able to fix the error by moving the call to `self.top.mainloop()` into your `__init__()` method.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.run()
    self.top.mainloop()

def run(self):
    song = self.title_of_window(self.SPOTIFY)
    if self.temp_song_name != song:
        lyric = self.get_lyric(song)
        self.add_lyric_to_tk(song,lyric)
    else:
        self.add_lyric_to_tk(song, "Not Found")
    self.top.after(5000,self.run)
```

Does this solve your problem?

*EDIT:* see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42053715/3594526) for a longer description of the problem.